# Как наиболее оптимально вычесть дату из даты и получить разницу в часах?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, datetime

Какой будет наиболее оптимальная реализация вычитания даты из даты?

Обе даты представлены в таком формате:
`Сб фев 13 14:21:12 2021` и `Сб фев 13 13:27:17 2021`.

Необходимо получить, сколько времени прошло между эти двумя датами в часах.
Например, 1 час и 30 минут, должно выдать 1.5. Часов можеть быть и 125, если прошло несколько дней.

Comment: Так вы свою реализацию покажите. Вдруг она и есть наиболее оптимальная?

Comment: она не оптимальная, потому я переводил Сб фев 13 13:27:17 2021 в 13 February 2021 (Saturday) 13:27:17. Мне так не нравится, можно проще,а у меня не получалось.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться удобным и универсальным модулем [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - он  умеет парсить строки с датами на разных языках:

Пример:

```
In [5]: from dateparser import parse

In [6]: d2 = parse("Сб фев 13 14:21:12 2021")

In [7]: d1 = parse("Сб фев 13 13:27:17 2021")

In [8]: res = d2 - d1

In [9]: res
Out[9]: datetime.timedelta(seconds=3235)

In [10]: str(res)
Out[10]: '0:53:55'
```

Время в минутах:

```
In [12]: res.total_seconds() / 60
Out[12]: 53.916666666666664
```

Время в часах

```
In [13]: res.total_seconds() / 3600
Out[13]: 0.898611111111111
```

Comment: спасибо, проблема была с тем, что не знал, как парсить имено РУССКИЙ язык, поэтому переводил с формат с английскими названиями месяцев и т.д.(что было ненужно)

Comment: @user99999, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)